Can't make metadata immutable
We are trying to update token info and make metadata immutable, but we always get error
Verified creators cannot be removed. 

Source: Program > mplTokenMetadata [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]

Caused By:
Error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 3: custom program error: 0x5e. 

Logs:
[
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program payTxVMsrh3oo81ocHb6xFge4vGUJenEFFa3sRdLNX2 consumed 16113 of 499700 compute units",
  "Program payTxVMsrh3oo81ocHb6xFge4vGUJenEFFa3sRdLNX2 success",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]",
  "Program log: IX: Update",
  "Program log: Auth type: Metadata",
  "Program log: Verified creators cannot be removed.",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 14016 of 483587 compute units",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x5e"
]

Catch the SendTransactionError and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.

Program Logs:
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program payTxVMsrh3oo81ocHb6xFge4vGUJenEFFa3sRdLNX2 invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: Payment
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program payTxVMsrh3oo81ocHb6xFge4vGUJenEFFa3sRdLNX2 consumed 16113 of 499700 compute units
| Program payTxVMsrh3oo81ocHb6xFge4vGUJenEFFa3sRdLNX2 success
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]
| Program log: IX: Update
| Program log: Auth type: Metadata
| Program log: Verified creators cannot be removed.
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 14016 of 483587 compute units
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x5e



The error says: "Program log: Verified creators cannot be removed.". It looks like your metadata update is invalid, so you might need to remove that step before making the metadata immutabl.e
